# Как сделать 6 блоков в одном блоке?

Tags: html, css

Как реализовать такой блок? Есть вот такое:

```css
.main {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 height:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -3px;
}
.main-curort-panel {
 width: 1000px;
 background-color: #b6a1cc;
 height:400px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
```

```html
 <div class="main">
  <div class="main-curort-panel">
   <div class="main-curort"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iWeVc.png): [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: данный вопрос в виде картинки следует закрыть, потому что он бесполезен для базы знаний (тот, у кого возникнет подобный вопрос, не сможет найти данный вопрос и ответы к нему)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот `inline-block` можна, можна `flex`, `grid`

```css
.main {
 width: 1200px;
 background-color: rgb(255,255,255);
 box-shadow: 0px 0 7px rgba(0,0,0,.1);
 height:100%;
 margin: 0 auto;
 margin-top: -3px;
}
.main-curort-panel {
 width: 1000px;
 background-color: #b6a1cc;
 height:400px;
 margin:0 auto;
}
.main-curort{
display:inline-block;
width:32%;
height: 187px;
background:#ffffff;
margin:0.5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="main-curort-panel">
   <div class="main-curort"></div>
      <div class="main-curort"></div>
      <div class="main-curort"></div>
      <div class="main-curort"></div>
      <div class="main-curort"></div>
      <div class="main-curort"></div>
  </div>
 </div>
```